# Unable to get the New Relic Trace ID from Header

Tags: java, newrelic, distributed-tracing

I've been trying to get the New Relic Trace/Transaction ID from the request for a traced service.

Unfortunately, I'm having trouble retrieving the value.

When I try to pull the values from the header, they are not getting populated.

I can get the Distributed payload, but am not fully sure what I'm looking at.

#### Results:

`@RequestHeader(name="X-NewRelic-ID", defaultValue="null")` = "null"
`@RequestHeader(name="X-NewRelic-Transaction", defaultValue="null")` = "null"
`NewRelic.getAgent().getTransaction().getRequestMetadata()` = null
`NewRelic.getAgent().getTransaction().getResponseMetadata()` = null

DistributedTracePayload =

```
{
  "d": {
    "ac": "1234567",
    "pr": 1.300000,
    "tx": "15c1855ad4955424",
    "ti": 1234567890123,
    "ty": "App",
    "tr": "13c1423ad1941424",
    "sa": true,
    "ap": "12345678"
  },
  "v": [
    0,
    1
  ]
}
```

#### Web Service:

```
import java.text.MessageFormat;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestHeader;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.bah.egis.recompete.service.JsonService;
import com.newrelic.api.agent.DistributedTracePayload;
import com.newrelic.api.agent.NewRelic;
import com.newrelic.api.agent.Trace;

import io.swagger.annotations.Api;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiOperation;

@RestController
@Api(value = "JSON API", tags = { "JSON REST Api" })
public class TestController {

    @Qualifier("jsonService")
    @Autowired
    private JsonService jsonService;

    @Trace(dispatcher=true)
    @CrossOrigin
    @ApiOperation(value = "Ingest JSON Data and do something with it")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/registerTraceID", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<String> registerTraceID(@RequestBody String jsonData, @RequestHeader(name="X-NewRelic-ID", defaultValue="") String newRelicID, @RequestHeader(name="X-NewRelic-Transaction", defaultValue="") String newRelicTransactionID) {
        String result;
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(newRelicID) && StringUtils.isBlank(newRelicTransactionID)) {
            DistributedTracePayload distributedTracePayload = NewRelic.getAgent().getTransaction().createDistributedTracePayload();
            if (distributedTracePayload == null) {
                result = "";
            } else {
                result = distributedTracePayload.text();
            }
        } else {
            result = MessageFormat.format("'{'X-NewRelic-ID: {0}, X-NewRelic-Transaction: {1}'}'", newRelicID, newRelicTransactionID);
        }
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(result);
    }
}
```